# Node.js, This is an error in module line-by-line ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Content of the files to read**

letters.txt

```
a
b
c
```

numbers.txt

```
0
1
2
```

I need read line by line in order

example:

```
a--0
a--1
a--2
b--0
b--1
...
```

Code :

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
    letters = new LineByLineReader('letters.txt');
    numbers = new LineByLineReader('numbers.txt');

letters.on('line', function (line) {
    readNumbers(line);
});


function readNumbers(letter){
    numbers.on('line', function (number) {
        console.log(letter+'--'+number);
    });
}
```

Output:

```
a--0
b--0
a--1
b--1
a--2
b--2
c--2
```

How to read in order and where is c -- 1 ?

Comment: Try a) not installing handlers aysynchronously b) just read the two files into two arrays, and then combine them.

Comment: looks like an issue with not understanding asynchronous code

Comment: Like mentioned, your getting into asynchronous issues.  There is a line-by-line-promise npm, that makes reading lines promise based, and with async / await would make this very easy.  @Bergi  maybe the actual files are large.

Comment: @Keith Then the output would be even larger? I don't know what OP is trying to accomplish. If streaming, we'd need to read in the numbers file multiple times, which I'd rather avoid at the expense of some memory for small inputs.

Comment: @Bergi  I agree, for small files I wouldn't even use Line-by-line, as it's overkill. Its really meant for large files / streaming.  I did recently use it for parsing MySQL dumps, these can get pretty big.  The dumps had errors in them, and I wanted a way to resume a dump.  ps:  I didn't end up using line-by-line-promise, as it's implementation is sub-optimal, I rolled my own wrapper over line-by-line..